# How to get older version of Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I need to run an older version of Chromium to make an extension work.

It can be an Ubuntu installation or Windows executable that I run with WINE. I just need a way to find and run an older version of Chromium.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can download it from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/). I'm not sure about the dependencies though.

Comment: the archives where Kulfy linked are the best place to find old versions.  You really should not use an outdated browser for your actual browsing however -- there is a reason that web browsers get frequent updates and only the most recent is supported - newer versions patch exploits and security holes.

Comment: The version I'd like to use it "69.0.3497.100". When I tried the .deb package it told me it couldn't install because of dependencies. Would you be able to tell me what to put in the terminal to make this version install?

Comment: I had "69.0.3497.100" installed through the Software Center until just yesterday. I guess they updated it? Is there a way I could run an executable of this Chromium version without installing it?